# How to implement the refresh/stop button in addres bar of the ios safari?

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari

Like the red marked refresh/stop button on the address bar, how can I create one like that?
Thank you very much!
[image: the safari on iphone]

Answer (score 1):

`UITextField` has `rightView` property. You can assign `UIButton` to that property. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

right just add a Button like this...

```
UIButton *theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
theText.rightView = theButton;
theText.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

But you will need the refresh and stop image as button image....